# BootStrap Dropdown with scrollbar display issue

Tags: html, twitter-bootstrap, css

I have a weird requirement where my dropdown items are exceeding the screen height so I am supposed to put a scroll bar. I have tried replicating the same with the fiddle below.

ScreenShot

[image]
[JSfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/shubh0602/fpajmhtz/)

```
.dropdown-submenu>.dropdown-menu {
    overflow-y: scroll;
    overflow-x: hidden;
    height: 80px;
}
```

Comment: descendent elements will always be clipped by the element with overflow: hidden.

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/hvx4zres/2/

Comment: @LaljiTadhani : I did not get the use of the fiddle :(

Comment: hello shubh... Have you got the solution? I am facing the same issue

Comment: @Curious_k.shree - No. Unfortunately not. :(